# "ByRef Argument Type Mismatch" Error on VBA UDF

Tags: excel, vba

This is the function that is giving the issue :

Its supposed to check if a string only has numbers 0-9

```
Public Function onlyNumbers(str As String)
        For i = 1 To Len(str)
        If Not (IsNumber(Mid(str, i, 1))) Then
            onlyNumbers = False
        End If
    Next
    onlyNumbers = True
End Function
```

Module:

```
    Dim value as string
For j = 2 to 2205
    value = Cells(j, 2)

    value = Trim(Replace(Replace(value, "-", ""), ".", ""))
   'Error gives on the if check (it highlights "value") :        
    If onlyNumbers(value) Then

   ' code goes on... no syntax error, execution only
```

Comment: Either add a `call` before or remove the `()`.

Comment: IsNumber is not vba.  Try IsNumeric()

Comment: Also your UDF will always return true.  You need to exit the function upon finding a false.

Comment: @ScottCraner in excel 2007 at least, that's how you return, setting a return gives syntax error

Comment: Which line is actually giving the issue?

Comment: You misunderstand,  if you do not exit the function after finding the false it will end the loop and then set the output to true.

Comment: @ScottCraner I do believe i'm right still, that's the effective syntax for a return in VBA, so it is exiting the function

Comment: nope, If you wanted to count the letters in the string the you would change  `onlyNumbers = False` to `onlyNumbers = onlyNumbers + 1` As it iterates it will count the number of non numeric values.  It does not exit just because you set a value to the function. It is a variable.  Therefore until you exit the function the final value can be changed.

Comment: And the problem is you are using `value` a word that is already used in vba,  change the variable to some non vba word like `vlu` or something.

Comment: @ScottCraner actually that was the issue haha, and the function logic mistake you found

Answer (score 3):

Just to save all the bother - you don't even need a function or a loop for this, just use the `Like` operator:

```
Dim myString As String

myString = "12345"

If myString Like Application.Rept("[0-9]", Len(myString) Then
    MsgBox "myString is numbers only"
Else
    MsgBox "myString contains other characters that aren't 0-9"
End If
```

---

If you *really* want that to be a function then:

```
Function IsNumbersOnly(str As String) As Boolean
    IsNumbersOnly = str Like Application.Rept("[0-9]", Len(str))
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Add:

```
 Dim value As String
```

at the beginning of the Sub.

Comment: My bad, it had that line just got cut

Answer (score 1):

It would appear people have given great advice in the comments, below is a working solution that takes in them and reduces the codebase.

```
Public Function onlyNumbers(ByVal str As String) As Boolean
For i = 1 To Len(str)
    If Not (IsNumeric(Mid(str, i, 1))) Then Exit Function
Next
onlyNumbers = True
End Function
```

Comment: Actually, because you have already taken out the minus and decimal point. You don't need the function at all `If IsNumeric(value) Then` instead of `If onlyNumbers(value) Then`.

Comment: exiting function automatically asign its return value to false?

Comment: @Mojimi yes, unless you specify a boolean value, its default is false

Comment: Put something in this that talks about the problem with the use of `Value` as a variable, so this then is the correct answer.

Comment: @Mojimi Also, just incase it is unknown. You do not have to close an `If` statement with `End If` is it is running a single commend  when triggered. I.e. if the content of the `If` state is a simple one line operation, you can put it on the one line and not add the `End If` as I have done. I have to do this a lot as code optimisation is a big task for me, however, it can make for difficult to follow code so I wouldn't say to do it if you're not sure or if the code is becoming overly complicated.

Comment: As @ScottCraner stated, you have used a 'reserved' word that is causing ambiguity in the code. Changing it to anything else like `vlu` or `StrValue` would fix this (I prefix my variables with their declaration type to know what I am dealing with at all times).

Answer (score 0):

Cells() returns a range object.

You need to set value to the value of the range.  Try Cells().value when calling your function.

```
value = Cells(j, 2)
value = Trim(Replace(Replace(value, "-", ""), ".", ""))
'Error gives on the if check :        
If onlyNumbers(value.value) Then
```

Comment: Actually, unless you use the `Set` keyword before the assignment the `Cells()` method default property is `.Value` so that is what gets returned when you don't specify.

Comment: Nope, that wasn't it

Comment: That's neat -- I didn't realize that.  Thanks Macro Man!

Answer (score 0):

4 errors

1) Exiting the loop for correct logic as pointed by @ScottCraner

2) Variable name "value" already used by vba, likely conflicting(error from question title) as pointed by @ScottCrane

3) Next i missing

4) IsNumber is not in VBA, the correct is IsNumeric as pointed by @ScottCraner

```
Public Function onlyNumbers(str As String)
        For i = 1 To Len(str)
        If Not (IsNumeric(Mid(str, i, 1))) Then
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
    onlyNumbers = True
End Function
```

Thanks for everyone who helped

Comment: I would still suggest you don't need the function at all, you are looping character by character to look for non-numeric entries in the string, You can pass the whole string into `IsNumeric` and get the same result, but you would have the benefit of no extra function to go into and no loop to go around.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you are having a problem with your Cells call.  Please change it to Cells(2, 10).  This will be j2 as this API is Cells(row, column) by index

```
Dim Value As String
Value = Cells(2, 10)

Value = Trim(Replace(Replace(Value, "-", ""), ".", ""))
Debug.Print onlyNumbers(Value)
```

And your other piece had some incorrect syntax because you shoudl use IsNumeric

```
Public Function onlyNumbers(str As String)
    For i = 1 To Len(str)
    If Not IsNumeric(Mid(str, i, 1)) Then
        onlyNumbers = False
    End If
Next
onlyNumbers = True
End Function
```

Comment: It's completely fine to use `j` in the `Cells()` method as long as `j` is a number, and your function will always return true

Comment: The original post did not have the variable J defined.  So when I re-built the code, my assumption (correct or not) was that J was intended to be the column heading.  The fact that the post was re-edited multiple times makes it appear as though I did not read - thanks for the negative from whomever that was.

Missing from original post:
    Dim value as string
For j = 2 to 2205